# Angular Service in Service not able to inject due to circular dependancy

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, circular-dependency, injectable

I have a service. When I inject another service into it. I get error related to params not defined. ServiceA (Object, Object, ?, Object)
I tried making a third service to separate out concerns as well but wont work. I tried to make another service for seperation of concerns and then importing that into my service, still getting the error.
Also included both service's in it's respective module.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are encouraged to make an attempt to write your code. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that. Please provide specific information about that attempt and what didn't work as expected. To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and its linked resources.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.